# Copying a Chart in VBA after Opening Excel File

Tags: vba, ms-word, excel-2007

I have a VBA Module in Word2007 with a main sub which calls an OpenExcelFile sub to open an Excel Workbook. It opens successfully, but then in my main sub, I am having trouble selecting and copying a particular chart. I want to then paste the chart into word as a picture.

```
Const Fuelpath As String = "\\PATH\Fuel_Price_Screen.xls"

Sub Main()
OpenExcelFile (Fuelpath)
'''This is where I would like to Copy the only Chart on the first Excel Sheet (named "$$Screen," 
'''but I keep getting errors. I would like to paste it into the Word doc called 
'''"daily summary automation," which the VBA module is running in.
End Sub

Sub OpenExcelFile(ByVal Filepath As String)
Dim xlApp As Object
xlApp.Application.Visible = True
xlApp.Workbooks.Open (Fuelpath)
End Sub
```

Comment: I added the following line after OpenExcelFile(Fuelpath)   Excel.Application.Workbooks("Fuel_Price_Screen.xls").Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap  But it gave a Subscript Out of Range Error. When hovering over the word "Application" (in "Excel.Application") I noticed "Application = Microsoft Word" came up as a hovertag.  Then I tried adding AppActivate ("Microsoft excel") directly above but then I got an "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument" error.